# Como executar um arquivo python como admin?

Tags: python

Estou Tentando executar um arquivo python, porem ele pede para ser executado como admin como q faço isso?

Comment: Windows, Linux ou Mac?

Comment: Eu uso o Windows

Answer (score 4):

## Windows

Execute o Prompt de Comando ou PowerShell com a opção Executar como Administrador.

Execute o comando normalmente:

```
> python seu_script.py
```

## Linux e Mac

No Terminal, use:

```
> sudo python seu_script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

está certo

```
python python_script.py
```

em windows

e

```
su
bash
chmod +x python_scrypt.py
sudo python python_script.py
```

em linux/osx

para instalar modulos de python (vamos supor, o tensorflow da google, por exemplo), terá de usar como comandos:

```
pip install myPythonExtenson
```

isto para python 2

para python 3 deverá correr

```
pip3 install myPythonExtension
```

Comment: A diferença entre sua resposta e dada anteriormente é apenas o indicativo de como fazer instalação de módulos via `pip`. Como não faz parte do escopo da pergunta, você pode converter esta resposta em um comentário da outra resposta, se julgar mesmo que essa informação seja pertinente ao tópico.

Comment: eu faria isso, de bom grado, mas não tenho ainda um score suficiente, para colocar comentários

Comment: para hchmar com "python" na frente, não precisa do "chmod + x" - o chmod é para quando voê quer executr o comando diretamente pelo nome dele.